# MongoDB aggregation get last element's field from nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to aggregate and display only the last object in a nested array
This is my DB:

```
[{
  "firstName": "Shaun",
  "salary": [
    {
    "id":1,
    "rate": 250,
    },
    {
    "id":2,
     "rate": 290,
    }
  ]
},{
  "firstName": "Julian",
  "salary": [
    {
    "id":1,
     "rate": 750,      
    },
    {
    "id":2,
     "rate": 760,      
    },
    {
    "id":3,
     "rate": 790,      
    },
  ]
}
}]
```

My desired result is :

```
{"firstName": "Shaun", "rate":290},{"firstName": "Julian", "rate":790}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below aggregation query which uses [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to get last element from array `salary.rate` :

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $project: {
    firstName: 1,
    rate: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$salary.rate", -1 ] }
  }
})
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gXIiJBcY8eX)